# Understanding Callback function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, callback, asynccallback

I am very new to **Node Js and Concept of Callback Mechanism** , I have working code to authenticate the User based on the LDAP using `ldapjs` but I wanted to know the mechanism how its working with respect to data flow and callbacks.

In the below code I have few doubts, Can someone help me clarifying

1. What does it means with `cb(err === null, err, res);`
2. When I do console.log with fake_res it shows as `true` Why its true?
3. I see some post referring we need use to error as first callback, Is it so?
4. And Finally I wanted to understand why is the res used in output and authDN are same
5. And finally how generally callbacks works in NodeJS

Before asking this question I have gone through many forums but couldn't relate with the below code

1. [Link 1](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7jfWhz67YAhUPymMKHVJiB5cQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffredkschott.com%2Fpost%2F2014%2F03%2Funderstanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js%2F&usg=AOvVaw12cy0kQsHgcuWuIh-RpJuS)
2. [Link 2](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7jfWhz67YAhUPymMKHVJiB5cQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffredkschott.com%2Fpost%2F2014%2F03%2Funderstanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js%2F&usg=AOvVaw12cy0kQsHgcuWuIh-RpJuS)
3. [Link 3](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7jfWhz67YAhUPymMKHVJiB5cQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffredkschott.com%2Fpost%2F2014%2F03%2Funderstanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js%2F&usg=AOvVaw12cy0kQsHgcuWuIh-RpJuS)
4. [Link 4](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7jfWhz67YAhUPymMKHVJiB5cQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffredkschott.com%2Fpost%2F2014%2F03%2Funderstanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js%2F&usg=AOvVaw12cy0kQsHgcuWuIh-RpJuS)

```js
var express = require('express');
var util = require('util');
CircularJSON = require('circular-json');
var router = express.Router();
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var userNT;
var password;


var app = express();

function authDN(dn, password, cb, res) {
  var client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://localhost:389'
  });
  client.bind(dn, password, function(err) {
    client.unbind();
    cb(err === null, err, res);
  });

}

function output(fake_res, err, res) {
  if (fake_res) {
    console.log('success');
    res.status(200).send('{"status":"success"}');

  } else {
    console.log('failure');
    res.status(401).send('{"status":"failure"}');
  }

}

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); // support encoded bodies

router.post('/login', postData);

function postData(req, res) {
  userNT = req.body.ntid;
  password = req.body.password;
  authDN(userNT, password, output, res);
};


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: are you well versed with LDAP itself and facing issues in understanding callback and stuff?

Comment: @TGW I just wanted to understand the Callback mechanism from the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let us go try to do it step by step :

Here if you see `authDN` has third parameter `cb` this is your callback function. Now to trace it back check the value of argument provided to this function `authDN` when it is called inside `postData` function, here **`cb = function output`**

Now first param of your output is fake_res which is either true or false, this depends on response of `client.bind`

If it fails you will get some error hence it will go on to be false. Here comes the answer to your **question 2** because your credentials seem to be correct always this **err is equal to null** thus your fake_res is always true.

Answering **question 4** it is because it is passed on as param to send response back to the API call you made using `router.post`

About **number 3** it is just more readable and better to use an error first callback, but not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the things and really helped me!!

Comment: Glad it helped, in case you're interested in how event loop in node works you might want to take a look  at [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)  and how callback comes in scene.